# I want to find the input checkbox and click with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying with :

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']").click()`

[image: CheckBox Element]

Comment: Please [Edit] your question with valid html or url and which element you are  trying to click?

Comment: I am trying to click the input type checkbox which is marked in the screenshot. I think this is an iframe. How to handle iframe with selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The `input` is inside an `iframe` you need to switch `iframe` first in order to access the input element.

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for input `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aplazame-checkout-iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"accepts_gdpr"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

To come out from `iframe` use.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
driver.find_element_by_name("accepts_gdpr").click()
```

Comment: can you show us the actual HTML or website link? it's maybe inside iframe or something like that.

Comment: https://cdn.aplazame.com/widgets/demo/#/order/test-1618496569190

Comment: @ssharkar i cant find button can you tell me the Name?

Comment: I found the button with this: driver.find_element_by_class_name("pay-with-aplazame").click()

Comment: Are you there? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no `input` tag with `type = 'checkbox'` anywhere in that URL you provided, so its impossible for us to help you.  What exactly are you trying to click on?